# Using Plotly to generate angled bar chart (Risk analysis from Dash)

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

Dash has this sample "[Financial Analysis](https://dash.gallery/dash-financial-report/overview)" app in their gallery, and there is one chart called "Risk Potential" that on the app states that it was built with Plotly.

[image]

Does anyone know which Plotly chart was used and how to build that kind of angled chart with a custom in-bar indicator?

Comment: Hi Edmond, it looks to me this is just an image not a plotly graph. Did you realize that there is no interactivity when the cursor move over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be built in simple way

- **bar** trace with uniform **y** values
- **filled area** laid on top to provide *angle*
- **markers+text** to plot bubble

Clearly this can then be extended to be a utility function to build this figure based on parameters.

```
go.Figure(
    [
        go.Bar(
            x=np.linspace(1, 5, 5),
            y=np.full(5, 1),
            marker={"color": np.linspace(1, 5, 5), "colorscale": "redor"},
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            x=[0.6, 0.6, 5.4, 0.6],
            y=[0, 1, 1, 0],
            fill="toself",
            fillcolor="white",
            mode="none",
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            x=[4],
            y=[0.4],
            text=[4],
            mode="markers+text",
            marker={"size": 80, "color": "white"},
            textfont={"size": 20},
        ),
    ]
).update_layout(
    xaxis={"visible": False},
    yaxis={"visible": False},
    showlegend=False,
    template="plotly_white",
)
```

[image]